# how can I summarize different columns to make totals by row?

Tags: sql, t-sql

how can I summarize different columns to make totals by row?
on the picture below you can see my statement, definitely is something wrong there because is returning NULL value, but I don't know what it is. I want to create a `TOTAL column summarizing WOSE, WO, SSSE and SS per row`. Could someone help me with that?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of null values in the columns -Use the following instead -

```
SUM(COALESCE(WOSE,0) +COALESCE(WO,0) + COALESCE(SSSE,0)+COALESCE(SS,0))
```